# How to add use Github Webhooks to deploy changes to a LEMP server running in Individual Docker Containers

Tags: github, webhooks

I have a server running **ubuntu 18.04** running 3 Docker containers for **Nginx, PHP, and MySql**. Everything seems to be working correctly within the application which right now is just a test wordpress blog. However I am attempting to add Github Webhook deployments and I am a little lost as to how I should proceed. A few options

1. Should I setup a webserver on the Host system and trigger a php file to run and execute `git pull`? I suppose I could subdomain it to keep SSL validation constant.
2. Is there a way to pass ssh keys to one of the containers such as the php one and allow that to pull from the repo? I tried this and ran into user and group permission `1000` issues.
3. Is there a way for the docker containered application of nginx to execute code on the host server(The naked server running docker)?
4. Is there a simpler solution that I am not thinking of involving deployments? I would prefer not to use a paid service.

Comment: It is a good question, but it is also a hard question, basically I think all these 4 parts of questions can be split to 3 different questions. As for question 1, I am very sure that you need a server for github web hook. Question 2, I can give you a certain answer too, it is yes.

Comment: Thanks @tim, I think I'm going to pursue one of those two routes. For number 1, I definitely know how to do and I guess another nginx server won't be too much more overhead. For Number 2 I'm not sure how to transfer those permissions but I'm betting its a `chmod` issue. I'll do some googling.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/) or [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to continuous delivery?

These tools help you to do some change in your server when you do a new pull request over your repo of GitHub.

I will show you one [project](https://github.com/hugolesta/multi-docker/blob/master/.travis.yml#L23) that I was worked using travis-ci where I could deploy my App on Aws or connecting to one host that has docker installed and make new changes.

I'll share you some continuous delivery articles below

[Travis continuous delivery](https://oncletom.io/2016/travis-ssh-deploy/)

[Jenkins SSH credentials setting](https://linuxtechlab.com/how-to-easily-add-ssh-credentials-on-jenkins-server/)

[Jenkins from scratch CI/CD](https://medium.com/@vineetcloudops/jenkins-from-scratch-ci-cd-950c29d6f211)

Try to get new knowledge about Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery, is the best way to automate those kinds of processes

Comment: Thanks Hugo, I am hoping to avoid adding a CI, I'm using a private repo so travis is out as I believe you have to pay. I've played with Jenkins in the past but I'd prefer not to have a whole server running just to handle webhooks as I do not need any build functionality on the code once it gets to the server. I'll definitely take a look at these for other projects that require building and testing.